# « Tout à l’heure »

Tags: expressions, usage, régionalismes

L’expression « tout à l’heure » est aujourd’hui comprise comme une référence à un temps rapproché du passé ou du futur, avec néanmoins un certain écart avec l’immédiat. Jadis, la même expression représentait ce que l’on entend aujourd’hui par « tout de suite » ou « à l’instant », et son utilisation par Jean de La Fontaine dans sa très célèbre fable *Le loup et l’agneau* continue aujourd’hui à exposer bien des gens, très tôt dans leur vie, à cette acception.

> **Le Loup et l’Agneau**
>
> La raison du plus fort est toujours la meilleure :
>   Nous l’allons montrer **tout à l’heure**.
>   Un Agneau se désaltérait
>   Dans le courant d’une onde pure.
>   Un Loup survient à jeun qui cherchait aventure,
>   Et que la faim en ces lieux attirait.
>   Qui te rend si hardi de troubler mon breuvage ?
>   Dit cet animal plein de rage :
>   Tu seras châtié de ta témérité.
>   - Sire, répond l’Agneau, que votre Majesté
>   Ne se mette pas en colère ;
>   Mais plutôt qu’elle considère
>   Que je me vas désaltérant
>   Dans le courant,
>   Plus de vingt pas au-dessous d’Elle,
>   Et que par conséquent, en aucune façon,
>   Je ne puis troubler sa boisson.
>   - Tu la troubles, reprit cette bête cruelle,
>   Et je sais que de moi tu médis l’an passé.
>   - Comment l’aurais-je fait si je n’étais pas né ?
>   Reprit l’Agneau, je tette encor ma mère.
>   - Si ce n’est toi, c’est donc ton frère.
>   - Je n’en ai point. - C’est donc quelqu’un des tiens :
>   Car vous ne m’épargnez guère,
>   Vous, vos bergers, et vos chiens.
>   On me l’a dit : il faut que je me venge.
>   Là-dessus, au fond des forêts
>   Le Loup l’emporte, et puis le mange,
>   Sans autre forme de procès.

Mon expérience personnelle ne m’a pas exposé à une utilisation contemporaine dans ce sens ancien, et le TLFi [le dénote vieilli](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/heure). Je demeure curieux de savoir s’il a localement survécu jusqu’à ce jour, en quelque région de la Francophonie.

Comment: Do you really find this usage outside the sphere of its normal meaning? It seems about equivalent to entry 10b in the TLFi link. Is that all that *vieilli*? (I don't ask as a native speaker, though, so I could be missing the particular ring of that sentence.)

Comment: I have never heard it used in real life in the sense of _‘right now’_ or _‘immediately’_, but I know from old writings it was the initial value of the expression. One of these _old writings_ being from La Fontaine, it tends to get a bit of representation in people's experience even nowadays, but it is clearly unusual for me to understand it as La Fontaine meant it. Every time I use or hear it, it means either 10b or 10c, there is systematically a gap, though always small, between _now_ and the moment it is referring to.

Comment: Right, but I think that gap occurs here too, though. "We are going to show it in just a moment (as the story progresses)" would work for that line, at least as well as what I now understand is your reading: "We are going to show it immediately" — particularly given the future tense. Such formulations often occur in English stories as well: "Slow and steady wins the race, as you will see shortly." (Or "presently"! — indeed, "soon" and "right away" are so nearly interchangeable in the context that it's not surprising that an English *or* French expression could bear both meanings.)

Comment: For another example of the first lines of a poem setting out what the rest will do in the *near future* in a moral poem (albeit one that far predated La Fontaine), take Christine de Pisan's "[Doulce chose est que mariage](http://ow.ly/FLNu30a26KS)" : "Doulce chose est que mariage, / Je le puis bien par moy prouver, / Voire, à qui mari bon et sage / A, comme Dieux m’a fait trouver." Having stated her moral, she then begins to make her case for it, giving rise to a difference in the "times" of the two utterances. (Tell me if that makes sense or if I'm beside your point!)

Comment: If I was as inspired as La Fontaine was and wanted to compose this fable today, I'd probably opt for _sur l’heure_, not _tout à l'heure_.

Comment: Interesting — then can you préciser the difference between *sur l'heure* and *tout à l'heure* that makes the one suitable and the other not, given that (I think) it's not about the presence of a gap in time?

Comment: Si  tu  ne  nous  fais  trouver  ton  maître  **tout  à  l'heure**, nous allons faire pleuvoir sur toi une ondée de coups de bâton. _(– Les fourberies de Scapin,_ Molière)  Comprendre: si tu ne t'y mets immédiatement...

Comment: The difference is only common usage. _Sur l'heure [présente]_ means there won't be any type of delays, while _tout à l'heure_ somewhat freed itself from immediacy, though it is still orbiting around current time (like the Moon around the Earth, for a physical analogy: no contact, though a link that prevent the full escape).

Comment: Hmm, okay. As far as I can see, the second nuance is applicable in the case of this fable. So the nuance is probably too subtle for a speaker of my level since it's hard to account for explicitly.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - yes, in France, it is _vieilli_ enough that we don't use it for that meaning at all anymore - well - I don't know if there are regions of France where it still in use. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

En France, cette expression n'est plus reconnue de nos jours que *comme une référence à un temps rapproché du passé ou du futur, avec néanmoins un certain écart avec l’immédiat*. L'usage dans le sens *tout de suite* n'existe plus, mais effectivement, cette fable de La Fontaine est très célèbre, et on sait en général le sens de *tout à l'heure* dans ce cas, pour avoir étudié ladite fable à l'école.